# getCurrentPosition doesn't call any of the callbacks in PhoneGap under iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

My program has a method that calls getCurrentPosition both with error
and success callbacks.
On Android it works perfectly.
On iOS it doesn't call any of the callbacks - neither the error nor
the success.

Any ideas why does it happen would  be welcome.

P.S.
I'm using Phonegap 1.4, upgrading have proved problematic some time
ago, but if it might help, I can invest the time to upgrade phonegap
to latest version.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is some code, altough not sure how will it help:

```
getLocation: function(successCallback, errorCallback){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position){
                var itmPosition = JSITM.gps2itm(new JSITM.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)); 
                geolocationHandler.reverseGeocode(itmPosition ,successCallback, errorCallback);
            },
            function(error){
                alert("error getting position: " + error.message);
                errorCallback("some error message");
            },
            { maximumAge: 10000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
}
```

Neither of the callbacks is invoked.

Comment: add some code.. then only easy to answer

Comment: Code added. Not sure how would it help.

Comment: It works in android, and I don't see any errors thrown neither in iOS console, nor when trying to run the same code in Chrome.